# How can you delete statically generated nextjs files on 404 and redirects?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

next.js is a bit of a magic black box when it comes to its internal web server that handles redirects and incremental static rebuilds.

One problem that can arise is the next.js memory (`isrMemoryCacheSize`) runs out and brings consequences.

One such consequence is that you might have generated a page that now resides in the `.next/server/pages` folder as a built html and json file, BUT you also delete this page in your CMS.
At this point you might do your due diligence and call `revalidate` on the relevant slug/page and next.js will happily serve a 404 instead.

But once the memory runs out, next.js will forget this is a 404, look on disk, see the built files and serve those instead. At this point your site is serving a deleted file and chaos ensues.

It is likely a contested issue whether or not this is expected behavior or not. Our whole team deems this NON-expected behavior. WHAT is unexpected? The fact that next.js does not delete the files when a page is returned as 404, or a redirect.

A solution would be to delete these built pages whenever your `getStaticProps` resolves in a 404 or redirect. But how would an implementation of this look?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use nodejs built in functions to specifically delete these files.

Pseudo code in your `getStaticProps`:

```
  import { purgeNextjsStaticFiles } from "functions/app/purgeNextjsStaticFiles";

  // [...] lots of code here [...]

  if (pageShouldReturn404) {
    await purgeNextjsStaticFiles(slug);

    return {
      notFound: true,
      revalidate: 120,
    };
  }

  if (pageShouldReturnRedirect) {
    const { redirectUrl, isPermanent } = infoAboutYourRedirect;

    await purgeNextjsStaticFiles(slug);

    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: redirectUrl,
        permanent: isPermanent,
      },
    };
  }

  // [...] lots of code here [...]
```

So we have an abstraction here on how to purge nextjs static files based on the current slug (which is an array of your path).

An implementation of such a function could be (file `functions/app/purgeNextjsStaticFiles`):

```
import { stat, unlink, readdir, rmdir } from "node:fs/promises";

const purgeNextjsStaticFiles = async (pathSlugs) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(pathSlugs) || pathSlugs.length < 1) {
    return false;
  }

  const fullSlugPath = `${process.env.PWD}/.next/server/pages/${pathSlugs.join(
    "/"
  )}`;

  const parentFolder = `${process.env.PWD}/.next/server/pages/${pathSlugs
    .slice(0, pathSlugs.length - 1)
    .join("/")}`;

  const htmlPath = `${fullSlugPath}.html`;
  const jsonPath = `${fullSlugPath}.json`;

  try {
    const htmlStat = await stat(htmlPath);
    const jsonStat = await stat(jsonPath);

    if (htmlStat && jsonStat) {
      try {
        await unlink(htmlPath);
        await unlink(jsonPath);

        if (pathSlugs.length > 1) {
          const readParent = await readdir(parentFolder);

          if (readParent.length === 0) {
            // the folder is now empty, let's delete it
            await rmdir(parentFolder);
          }
        }
      } catch (unlinkError) {
        console.error(
          `Error trying to purge nextjs static files with base (ending in .json or .html) ${fullSlugPath}`
        );

        console.error(unlinkError);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // expected in certain scenarios, stating non existant files etc
  }
};

export { purgeNextjsStaticFiles };
```

This function deletes the html and json files when called, if they exist. If the folder they lie in becomes empty, the folder is also deleted.

Comment: This is legit, I owe you a coffee or beer @Tackle